# How to set C# library path for an application?

Tags: c#, .net, gac, distribution

I have C# application that uses a dll. When I try to run the application, it can't find the dll, unless it is in the same directory or in GAC. I do not want to have it in the same directory and I do not want to install it to GAC.
Is there any way how to tell the application where to look for the library? (For example if I want to distribute the application to customers and they want to use their own applications that would use the dll.)

Added:

I would like to have this file structure:

MainFolder: Libraries, Applications

Libraries: lib.dll

Applications: app1.exe

I don't want to copy it to GAC or have lib.dll in folder Applications. Is it possible?

Comment: Tamara, it is also possible to edit your previous question. That would be the preferred way.

Comment: Tamara, this question is very much like this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629459/c-cannot-find-library-during-runtime

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend that the applications of your customers copy the dll's they use in their own directory.

VB6 used to share dll's between applications, we have a term for this: [DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell)

Comment: Please use the more modern term for "DLL Hell" ---> The Global Assembly Cache. =) I think MS meant well ("The road to hell is...") when they made the GAC, but it feels like the same old pain... app weirdness, missing functions, extra deployment steps, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Follow [this guide on MSDN: Specifying an Assembly's Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx)

Comment: Is'n this basically the same as copying to GAC?

Comment: No, they are conceptually different. You can even reroute an assembly installed in GAC to another version by this method. You have to edit machine configuration or put the DLL in a subdirectory. I doubt any of them is what you want, but as GvS and Jon pointed out, this is not a good thing in general

Answer (score 4):

In your Main:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s,e)=>{
    var filename = new AssemblyName(e.Name).Name;
    var path = string.format(@"C:\path\to\assembly\{0}.dll",  filename);
    return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
 };
```

Add some exception handling to that

Comment: Thanks; in my case, our users all install specific product SDK and we know roughly where the library is. The AssemblyResolve event handler was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

The DLL will have to either be in the GAC or in the application's directory or a subdirectory, as the answers to your earlier question said.

If your customers want to write their own applications using the DLL, you should either install it in the GAC or get them to copy the DLL too. Having multiple copies of the library doesn't *sound* like a good thing, but it really is: it means you can upgrade one copy to a different version without breaking everything else.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible without the GAC, but assemblies must be strong named and you must make changes to app.config whenever the version or publickeytoken changes. This is what I have
Main Program in \, Shared libs in \Shared. and a sub program I want separated in \SDK, it uses ..\Shared for the assemblies.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="shared" />
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="protobuf-net" publicKeyToken="257b51d87d2e4d67" />
         <codeBase version="1.0.0.282" href="../protobuf-net.dll"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="SevenUpdate.Base" publicKeyToken="5d1aea1de74f122c" />
         <codeBase version="11.5.4.0" href="../SevenUpdate.Base.dll"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="SharpBits.Base" publicKeyToken="5d1aea1de74f122c" />
         <codeBase version="11.5.5.0" href="../SharpBits.Base.dll"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows" publicKeyToken="5d1aea1de74f122c" />
         <codeBase version="11.5.5.0" href="../System.Windows.dll"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="WPFLocalizeExtension" publicKeyToken="5d1aea1de74f122c" />
         <codeBase version="11.5.5.0" href="../WPFLocalizeExtension.dll"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my answer on your previous question:

Use [Assembly Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(vs.71).aspx) instructions in your app.config or machine.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can log, and then view the actions the framework took trying to load an assembly. This makes diagnosing assembly load errors very easy.

The tool to do both is "FUSLOGVW.exe" (Fusion Log Viewer, Fusion being the name of the loader) and included in the SDK.